# Encryption and Decryption Rijndael algorithm C# and WPF

Tags: c#, cryptography, aes

I have 1 TextBox in which the encryption key is entered, 2 ButtonEnc and ButtonDec buttons. When using saveFileDialog, nothing happens, an empty file is saved, and the Encrypt method error Encryption failed!", "Error.
I can't save encryption/Decryption file.
How can I change the code so that everything works as it should?

```
    private void ButtonEnc_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog dlg = new Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog();
        Microsoft.Win32.SaveFileDialog dlg1 = new Microsoft.Win32.SaveFileDialog();

        Nullable<bool> result = dlg.ShowDialog();
        Nullable<bool> result1 = dlg1.ShowDialog();

        sKey = TextBox1.Text;
        if (result == true)
        {
            string inputFile = dlg.FileName;
            dlg1.Filter = "aes documents (.aes)|*.aes";
            if (result1 == true)
            {
                sKey = TextBox1.Text;
                string outputFile = dlg1.FileName;
                EncryptFile(inputFile, outputFile);
            }
        }
    }

    
    private void EncryptFile(string inputFile, string outputFile)
    {
        try
        {
            sKey = TextBox1.Text;
            string password = sKey; 
            UnicodeEncoding UE = new UnicodeEncoding();
            byte[] key = UE.GetBytes(password);
            string cryptFile = outputFile;
            FileStream fsCrypt = new FileStream(cryptFile, FileMode.Create);
            RijndaelManaged RMCrypto = new RijndaelManaged();
            CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(fsCrypt,
                RMCrypto.CreateEncryptor(key, key),
                CryptoStreamMode.Write);
            FileStream fsIn = new FileStream(inputFile, FileMode.Open);
            int data;
            while ((data = fsIn.ReadByte()) != -1)
                cs.WriteByte((byte)data);
            fsIn.Close();
            cs.Close();
            fsCrypt.Close();
        }
        catch
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Encryption failed!", "Error");
        }
    }

    private void DecryptFile(string inputFile, string outputFile)
    {
        {
            sKey = TextBox1.Text;
            string password = sKey; 
            UnicodeEncoding UE = new UnicodeEncoding();
            byte[] key = UE.GetBytes(password);
            FileStream fsCrypt = new FileStream(inputFile, FileMode.Open);
            RijndaelManaged RMCrypto = new RijndaelManaged();
            CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(fsCrypt,
                RMCrypto.CreateDecryptor(key, key),
                CryptoStreamMode.Read);
            FileStream fsOut = new FileStream(outputFile, FileMode.Create);
            int data;
            while ((data = cs.ReadByte()) != -1)
                fsOut.WriteByte((byte)data);
            fsOut.Close();
            cs.Close();
            fsCrypt.Close();
        }
    }


    private void ButtonDec_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Microsoft.Win32.SaveFileDialog dlg1 = new Microsoft.Win32.SaveFileDialog();
        Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog dlg = new Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog();

        Nullable<bool> result = dlg.ShowDialog();
        Nullable<bool> result1 = dlg1.ShowDialog();

        sKey = TextBox1.Text;
        dlg.Filter = "aes files |*.aes";

        dlg.Multiselect = false;
        if (result == true)
        {
            string inputFile = dlg.FileName;

            if (result1 == true)
            {
                string outputFile = dlg1.FileName;
                DecryptFile(inputFile, outputFile);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please remove the unnecessary blank space in your code.

Comment: Then catch an exception and output its message (at least). Also step into the method with the debugger and check if the file paths actually are what you expect them to be.